# Azure, R: showing the Standard Error

Tags: r, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-machine-learning-service

When I develop an experiment on Azure ML I have the chance to insert the "Execute R Script" module. When I have runned it, I can explore the outputs produced by the module itself.

[image: The output window]

My problem is that I have two modules: I do a filtering on a dataset in the first and use the resulting dataset in the second.
Then I create a web service with it.
Problem: when the filtering gives a null dataset this possibly create problems in the functions on the second module.

I want to find a way to "write" in the "Standard Error" space. I have tried to use:

```
if (length(dataset$column1)==0) {warning("Empty filtering!!!!")}
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

According to the R manual for [the `NULL` object](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/NULL.html), please try to use the function `is.null(x)` as the `if` condition.

Meanwhile, as notice, there are two similar concepts `NA` & `NULL` in R, please refer to the blog http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-na-vs-null/ to know the difference, and use the function `is.na(x)` instead of `is.null(x)` for a `NA` object.

Comment: Anyways, in the "Standard Error" section I cannot print anything. Only errors will be shown there... right?

Comment: @AndreaIanni௫, Right.